# How do you handle click events inside a jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

How do you handle click events inside a plugin? A simplified description is that I want to have a plugin that will detect a click and then update another element.

**Example Usage:**

`$("#some_id").myPlugin("another_id");`

**Example Plugin:**

```
(function($){

     $.fn.myPlugin=function(update_id){

     .click({$(update_id).html("content_upated");});

     }

})(jQuery);
```

I don't understand how to code the .click event inside the plugin. Any examples would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should do two things:

1. Use `this` to reference the elements to which your plugin is being applied
2. [Namespace your events](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Events), so they can easily be unbound later

Try the following

```
(function($){

     $.fn.myPlugin = function(update_id) {

       this.bind("click.myPlugin", function () {
         $(update_id).html("content_upated");
       });

    };

})(jQuery);
```

You should read the page on [jQuery plugin authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) for more information on how to correctly develop jQuery plugins. You're missing other important details like accepting an arguments object.

Comment: +1 using the event namespace is definitely a good idea. My only suggestion is to `.unbind()` the same namespaced event before binding it to prevent duplicate event handlers in case the plugin is called multiple times on the same element.

Comment: +1 to this as it covered namespacing as well which I hadn't considered, great answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I understand how to do this now and will work on using namespacing as well.

Comment: Could you update this to use the new .on() method for clicks? Thanks!

Comment: "As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .on() method for attaching event handlers to a document since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged." from the JQuery api

Answer (score 1):

Use `this` to access the object that the plugin is being invoked on:

```
(function($){
     $.fn.myPlugin=function(update_id){
         this.click( function() { $(update_id).html("content_upated"); } );
     }
})(jQuery);
```

Note that your usage would need to include the id selector in this example, or you would need to include it in your click function:

```
$("#some_id").myPlugin("#another_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

You would invoke `.each()` to iterate over the matched elements, or you can attach via regular jQuery method.

```
(function($)
{
     $.fn.myPlugin = function(anotherIdentifier)
     {
          // this.click is equivalent to $(identifier).click()
          this.click(function()
          {
              // Thing to do
          });
     };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($){
     $.fn.myPlugin=function(update_id){
         this.click(function(){ $(update_id).html("content_upated"); });
     }
})(jQuery);
```

Make sure `update_id` is a valid selector.

Answer (score -2):

```
(function($){   
     $.fn.myPlugin=function(update_id){ 
         this.click(function(){ $(update_id).html("content_upated"); });
     }
})(jQuery);
```

Make sure `update_id` is a valid selector.

Comment: Probably because you didn't take the time to explain anything in your answer, so it's hardly an answer. It's more important that you explain *why* and *how* you fixed something, rather than simply posting the fixed code.